# Turn String Into Hyperlink with Preset Name in Excel with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a userform where I will be wanting people to enter a link e.g. bbc.com & I want the program to automatically turn this string into a hyperlink (blue underlined) called "website".

Here's what I have so far.

```
PublicProperty Get Link() as string
Link=Me.Linkbvalue    
.cells(blankrow,1).value=me.link
```

EDIT: Note, words generic to protect company. Actually the problem is not it starting with local server. In the following the file is in the folder but not the subfolder

Entry="\directory\folders_directory\folder\file"

when running code, 
address becomes

\directory/folders_directory\folder\sub_folder"\directory\folders_directory\folder\file"

Comment: Take a look at the [Hyperlinks.Add Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.hyperlinks.add).

Comment: So I would just use hyperlinks.Add( Anchor:=.cells(blankrow,1) , Address:=Link , TextToDisplay:="Website" )?

Comment: @Napolean - almost - you need to write define the worksheet before the `Hyperlink.Add` and to get rid of the parenthesis. Pretty much the example from learn.microsoft.com can be used as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following might help.
It will convert column A values to hyperlinks.

```
Sub GetHyperlink()
   For Each xCell In Range("A:A")
      If xCell.Value <> "" Then
         ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=xCell, Address:="http://www." & Replace(xCell.Formula, "www.", ""), TextToDisplay:="Website" 
      End If
   Next xCell
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi thanks for this. Please can you tell me what the replace is doing in this code?

Comment: It's just replacing the "www." with nothing from the cell value as we are adding "httpcolondoubleslashwww." on the cell value explicitly, e.g. "wwwdotcnndotcom" will be treated as cnn.com and then "httpcolondoubleslashwww." will be added ("httpcolondoubleslashwwwdotcnndotcom") to make the full site address.

Answer (score 0):

This is something that should work, if you read the the `entry` variable from the `Form`:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim entry As String
    entry = "bbc.com"

    Dim httpPrefix As String
    httpPrefix = "https://"

    If Left(entry, Len(httpPrefix)) <> httpPrefix Then
        entry = httpPrefix & entry
    End If

    With Worksheets(1)
        .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Cells(1, 1), _
                Address:=entry, _
                TextToDisplay:="website"
    End With

End Sub
```

Some business logic is needed to decide whether to write `https://` or `http://` or anything similar. You may consider using `Trim()` to remove possible empty cells from the left and the right.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your great help. This works very well, except for files because instead of the address being 'entry', it prepends 'entry' it with the local server with the result that the 'file specified cannot be opened'. Please can you tell me what to do about this? Thanks

Comment: @Napolean - can you give an example?

Comment: Please see my edit to the OP. The issue is not what I thought. Don't know whether the weird placement of the commas in the errant link is suggestive

Comment: @Napolean - still missing your point. Can you write explicitly - how it looks like initially and how it should look like after adding the hyperlink?

Comment: The first is what it looks like when the user enters it in (which is what it should be), & the second is what the hyperlink ends up pointing to.

Comment: Hi, do you need any more info? In my edit in the OP 'entry' is what the user inputs as a string but then the code to input a hyperlink with that as the address for some reason prepends the 'entry' with something erroneous.

Comment: @Napolean - more info is needed. Can you make a [mcve] of the problem? Then write 3 things - what is the input, what is the output, what is the expected output.