# Convert string variable to hyperlink

Tags: excel, vba

I declared a variable

```
Dim xFolder As String
```

After some steps this variable turns into string-link to the file (pdf) in the specified folder (on local drive):

```
xFolder = xFolder & "\" & "NFK_PKA _" & ActiveSheet.Cells(6, 3).Value & ".pdf"
```

After next few steps this variable is placed into body of an email:

```
.HTMLBody = strbody1 & xFolder & Signature
```

The "pasted" link is a non-active text. I need an active hyperlink to that file on our local drive.

How could I convert from text to a hyperlink?

Comment: Is this what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52153992/turn-string-into-hyperlink-with-preset-name-in-excel-with-vba

Comment: I don't have Outlook to test it. As a html, you can try `<a href="D:/temp/test.pdf">Click to View PDF</a>`

Answer (score 1):

taller_ExcelHome it works! So simple!

```
<a href="D:/temp/test.pdf">Click to View PDF</a>
```

Thank you for suggestions!